# Nextjs preloaded scripts blocked with strict CSP

Tags: next.js, content-security-policy

I am trying to set up [strict CSP](https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html) in my next app based on the [next.js example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-strict-csp/pages/_document.js). In my `_document.js` I have the following:

```js
const cspHashOf = (text) => {
  const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256')
  hash.update(text)
  return `'sha256-${hash.digest('base64')}'`
}

let cspStr = ''
for (let k in csp) {
  cspStr += `${k} ${csp[k]}; `
}
```

...

```js
    render() {
    const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(8).toString('base64')

    let csp = {
      'object-src': "'none'",
      'base-uri': "'self'",
      'script-src': `'nonce-${nonce}' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' https: http: ${cspHashOf(
        NextScript.getInlineScriptSource(this.props)
      )}`,
    }

    let cspStr = ''
    for (let k in csp) {
      cspStr += `${k} ${csp[k]}; `
    }

    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <meta httpEquiv="Content-Security-Policy" content={cspStr} />
          ...
        </Head>
        <body>
          ...
          <NextScript nonce={nonce} />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
```

In the rendered page, I have all these preloaded chunks coming from Next which are getting blocked

```
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/8be9d4c0d98df170721d8fe575c2a4bcd5b2fbe4.e7c8a9ea6074f4dcaa51.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/863050a7585a2b3888f2e4b96c75689f1ae4a93d.a73c594ed7ed04a682dc.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/be8560b560b3990e61cbef828a20e51dc9370d83.4acbf8ef4e1b51b0bc0f.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/be8560b560b3990e61cbef828a20e51dc9370d83_CSS.6164c81b6ed04bb13dbd.js" as="script">
```

How do I prevent them from being blocked?

Comment: Just want to point out that if you're using a hash for your scripts you don't necessarily need to use a nonce. The old `with-strict-csp` Next.js example used to have the nonce, but [it's been updated it to use a hash](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/12042) instead.

Comment: thanks @juliomalves - I'm using the nonce for all my 3rds party scripts so it's easier to have it included consistently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was eventually able to resolve this by also passing the `nonce` as a prop to `Head`

```
<Head nonce={nonce}>
```

The documentation around this from Next.js is non-existent! I'd love if anyone finds it to share the link

Comment: If you wish to allow preload of scripts, you just need to add 'nonce-value' into `<link rel="preload" href="some_script.js" as="script" nonce="{nonce}">` tag. Do you mean that NextJS automatically redistribute the `nonce="{nonce}"` attribute from the `<head nonce="{nonce}">` section to nested `<link>` tags?

Comment: Yes. Without passing nonce to the nextjs <Head> component, the preload tags it generates don't have the nonce

Comment: Thanks!!!! I've tried to find this in docs and found nothing.